# How to show multiple geometry on geometry click in a-frame?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I want to show multiple spheres on a sphere click in a-frame. Suppose I have a sphere and when I will take my cursor to that sphere it will show other spheres and when I click on one of the multiple spheres it will show another multiple spheres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, if the spheres are predefined, or "procedural".

If You want to make new spheres on every sphere click, You can make a new component for the scene, listening for any click on any `a-sphere`, and attaching new spheres to the target:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo',{
  init:function(){
     document.querySelector("a-sphere").addEventListener('click',this.createSpheres);
  },
  createSpheres:function(){
    let sphere1 = document.createElement('a-sphere');
    sphere1.setAttribute('position','-1 1 1');
    let sphere2 = document.createElement('a-sphere');
    sphere2.setAttribute('position','2 1 2');
    let sphere3 = document.createElement('a-sphere');
    sphere3.setAttribute('position','-1 -1 -1');
    e.target.appendChild(sphere1);
    e.target.appendChild(sphere2);
    e.target.appendChild(sphere3);
  }
});
```

What i do here, is check for the click -> call the function responsible for sphere creation.

As far as i know, document.querySelector() shouldn't be working, since it should pick the 'first' found selector, but for some reason it works here.

Live example here: https://jsfiddle.net/wqbxnakr/.

---

For predefined objects, just make their first child visible on click:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('bar',{
  init:function(){
    this.el.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
       this.el.children[0].setAttribute('visible','true');
    }
  }
});
```

and attach the component to each chained sphere.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this kind of thing.

Comment: @RajaBabu glad i could help, it should be easy to randomize the position/color/whatever attribute of the generated spheres

Comment: Yes, I can use aframe random color lib.

Comment: @RajaBabu sure, If You have any further questions feel free to ask !